# Looking for or to create a logic of < or >

Tags: app-inventor

In AppInventor2 we drag logic down there is = , not = , and, or, but I can't seem to find the greater or less than logic. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: have you seen this..? : http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/reference/blocks/math.html

Answer (score 0):

[see the documentation of the math blocks in App Inventor 2](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/math.html)

[image]